# Show related nodes of a specific type when looking at a node of a different type

Tags: views, panels

I have a custom content type `Topic`, another custom content type `Sub-Topic`, and a taxonomy `Topic Tags`.  I'd like to be able to display the sub-topics on the page for each topic that has any of the same topic tags.

I'm using panels to define how pages look topics, and I was trying to use a view for the sub-topics.  I can make a view that filters by a specific tag, but I can't figure out how to pass the tags that the topic node has to the sub-topic view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into using the "context" module for this.

With it you would be able to set "conditions" and "reactions". The condition, being if your `topic` node is visited, `react` by showing a view block of the sub-topics. You can configure said block view to show the taxonomy tags based on certain criteria.

Comment: We ended up not needing to do this, but this works for me.